# Extend a generic class in swift

Tags: swift, generics

I have some code which has to be available on all `UIViewController` of application. So I created a `class UIViewControllerExtension: UIViewController`, which will be extended by each class which I want to use as `UIViewController`. Which works as expected.

Now I have new screens where I have to use `UITableViewController`, so I can't extend same class `UIViewControllerExtension`, And to keep code centralized so I do not want to create another `class UITableViewControllerExtension` with same code, and want to have a common solution for both cases.

I tried various ways to extend generic class `<T:UIViewController>` so I can use it in both cases, but it didn't work (as it wouldn't compile). I did some research on internet but didn't find any solution to it. Does someone had same issue and have a solution?

I thought if there would be some solution like

```
class  CommonViewController<T:UIViewController>: T{    //I know it doesn't compile
//...
}
```

Usage:

```
class MyHomeScreenViewController: CommonViewController<UIViewController>{
}

class MyItemListScreenViewController: CommonViewController<UITableController>{
}
```

I am open to any other solution if it solves my problem.

**Edit: More details**

1> I would like to extend `viewDidLoad()` method of `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` in common way (no duplication of code as said before)

2> I would like to add some supporting methods to UIViewController (and UITableViewController), supporting methods like `navigateBack`, `loginUser(name:String,password:String)` etc..

Comment: Why not simply make an `extension UIViewController { }` ?

Comment: @jtbandes If I do it, would it reflect extended methods on `UITableViewController` too automatically? And is it right to extend `didViewLoad()` method with same approach or it can cause any problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It is explained in description but in short There are 2 things, I want to override `didViewLoad()` method to add navigation bar related code, so all views in my application get it automatically, and I want to add some supporting methods which can make work easy for view controllers which extends it.

Comment: Those details are not explained in the question. Please [edit] and describe in detail what methods you want to add. The answer will depend on this.

Comment: @jtbandes details added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to extend `UIViewController` to add additional functionality to all `UIViewControllers` and override `viewDidLoad` in your own classes:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func navigateBack() {
        ...
    }

    // an extension cannot override methods
    // so this method gets called later in an overridden viewDidLoad
    func viewDidLoadNavigate() {
        ...
    }
}

// you own classes
class MyHomeScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    // you have to make sure that all view controllers which can navigate override viewDidLoad
    override viewDidLoad() {
        // optional call to super
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // this is needed and called from the extension
        viewDidLoadNavigate()
    }
}

class MyItemListScreenViewController: UITableViewController {

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewDidLoadNavigate()
    }
}
```

As you can see there is some code duplication but this is necessary since `UITableViewController` can also override `viewDidLoad`.

If generic inheritance is possible some day this code duplication can be reduced.